# importing from excel to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I am trying to import data from excel to MySQl below is my code , problem here is that it only writes the last row from my excel sheet to MySQl db and i want it to import all the rows from my excel sheet.

```
import pymysql
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\SqlExcel\Backup.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='test')



cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO report_table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        fname   = sheet.cell(r,1).value
        lname   = sheet.cell(r,2).value


values = (fname, lname)

cursor.execute(query, values)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: This is normal: you read `fname` and `lname` after your loop into `values`. At this time, they contain the last content they got within the loop. You should write every `fname`/`lname` pair already in the loop into your database or collect them in an array and finally write this one.

Comment: @SpghttCd I am new to this can please guide me little bit how to do so ?

Comment: Ok, now you have three people telling you to add two indents - should be sufficient guidance... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is currently only storing the last pair, and writing that to the database. You need to call `fname` and `lname` inside the loop and write each pair seperately to the database.

You can ammend your code to this:

```
import pymysql
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\SqlExcel\Backup.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='test',
                             autocommit=True)

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO report_table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

# loop over each row
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    # extract each cell
    fname   = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    lname   = sheet.cell(r,2).value

    # extract cells into pair
    values = fname, lname

    # write pair to db
    cursor.execute(query, values)

# close everything
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

**Note:** You can set `autocommit=True` in the connect phase. PyMySQL disables autocommit by default. This means you dont have to call `cursor.commit()` after your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot is worked for , the error was of indentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable values have to be inside the for instruction like this :

```
import pymysql
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\SqlExcel\Backup.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='test')



cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO report_table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        fname   = sheet.cell(r,1).value
        lname   = sheet.cell(r,2).value
        values = (fname, lname)
        cursor.execute(query, values)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know much about databases, so nor about pymysql. But assumed all the rest is correct I *guess* it could work like:

```
...
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO report_table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        fname   = sheet.cell(r,1).value
        lname   = sheet.cell(r,2).value

        values = (fname, lname)
        cursor.execute(query, values)


connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you will do on a regular basis? I see the script you're writing but I am not sure if this is something you need to run over and over again or if you are just importing the data into MySQL once.

If this is a one shot deal, you can try this.

Open the spreadsheet and SELECT ALL then COPY all your data. Paste it into a text document and save the text document (let's say the text document will be in c:\temp\exceldata.txt). You can then load it all into the table with one command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/temp/exceldata.txt'
INTO TABLE report_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I am making a few assumptions here:

1. The spreadsheet has only two columns and they are in the same order as the fields in your table.
2. You do NOT need to clear out the table before the load. If you do, issue the command TRUNCATE TABLE report_table; before the load.

Note, I chose a tab delimited format because I prefer it. You could save the file as a .CSV file and adjust the command as follows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/temp/exceldata.txt'
INTO TABLE report_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The "optionally enclosed by" is there because Excel will put quotes around text data with a comma in it.

If you need to do this on a regular basis, you can still use the CSV method by writing an excel script that saves the file to a .CSV copy whenever the spreadsheet is saved. I have done that too.

I have never written python but this is how I do it in PHP.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me after taking help from the above suggestion the error was of indentation now its working  :)

```
import pymysql
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\SqlExcel\Backup.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='test',
                             autocommit=True)



cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO report_table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):


        fname   = sheet.cell(r,1).value
        lname   = sheet.cell(r,2).value
        values = (fname, lname)
        cursor.execute(query, values)




cursor.close()
connection.close()
```